# Lombok annotations give Malicious code error - May expose internal representation by returning reference to mutable object error

Tags: java, lombok

I have the following class.

```
// Adding Lombok's @Data / @Value gives an error
public class Sample {

    String id;

    String name;

    Dummy[] entries;

    @JsonCreator
    // @Builder --> This gives same error
    private Sample(
            @JsonProperty("id") final String id,
            @JsonProperty("name") final String name,
            @JsonProperty("entries") @NonNull final Dummy[] entries) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.entries = entries;
    }
}
```

If I add Lomobok annotations, I get the following error. We heavily rely on Lombok and I am trying to figure out how I can ensure I don't return a mutable object.

```
EI_EXPOSE_REP: May expose internal representation by returning reference to mutable object

EI_EXPOSE_REP2: May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object
```

As an alternative, I could use List instead of Array and rely on @Singular annotation. But I would like to know if there is a workaround for Array with Lombok's annoations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FindBugs raises a bug called EI\_EXPOSE\_REP caused by Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298842/findbugs-raises-a-bug-called-ei-expose-rep-caused-by-array)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! However it doesn't solve my issue as I am relying on Lombok for @Builder, Getter and Setter. So I am trying to find if this is even possible with Lombok to use an array?

Comment: Afaik there's no possibility in lombok to configure to generate immutable arrays. You might try to implement the `getter` for that field on your own by using `Arrays.copyOf`. But I'm unsure this will help.

Comment: just write it by hand.

Answer (score 10):

One way to solve this is to add some lombok config. The way to do this is in the root of the project (the same place your pom.xml/build.gradle is) add a file called:

`lombok.config`.

In this file add the following lines:

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
lombok.extern.findbugs.addSuppressFBWarnings = true
lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties = true
```

More info here:
https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration

Answer (score 3):

It's an old and well known problem with methods generated by Lombok that return or accept mutable objects or structures.
For example [this issue about Date](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/420) was submitted in 2015.
It is unlikely that Lombok will ever fix this because it's non-trivial.
Your options :

1. Disable particular FindBugs/SpotBugs inspection via build tool plugin or IDE configuration.
2. Place @SuppressFBWarnings with relevant error code on violating class.
3. Use `onX` Lombok feature to let it place @SuppressFBWarnings on violating methods(setters,getters etc.) like in snippet below.

```java
@Data
@Setter(onMethod_ = @SuppressFBWarnings({"EI_EXPOSE_REP2","EI_EXPOSE_REP"}))
@Getter(onMethod_ = @SuppressFBWarnings({"EI_EXPOSE_REP2","EI_EXPOSE_REP"}))
public class TheClass {
    private MutableClassOrStructure classOrStructure;
}
```