# How to solve EI_EXPOSE_REP in records for Lists

Tags: java, list, spotbugs, java-record

Spotbugs raises a warning EI_EXPOSE_REP (May expose internal representation by returning reference to mutable object) for the following code:

```java
public record Example(
    List<String> ex) {

  public Example {
    ex =  List.copyOf(new ArrayList<>(ex));
  }
}
```

In [FindBugs raises a bug called EI_EXPOSE_REP caused by Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298842/findbugs-raises-a-bug-called-ei-expose-rep-caused-by-array) something like that is proposed as a solution. But it does not seem to work anymore. Any hints how to resolve that? Is that a bug in Spotbugs? If there is no other way then to suppress it: Is it possible to suppress in on field level instead of on class level?

At the end I will need a solution which also works in a Null - Safe manner. For that I introduced an own `copyOf` method. Would be great if the solution at the ends work in that null safe manner. (But the Spotbugs warning appears independently if I use my own `copyOf` method, or the one in `java.util.List`)

```
public static <T> List<T> copyOf(List<T> listToCopy) {
    if (listToCopy == null) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    //noinspection Java9CollectionFactory: cannot be replaced as List.copyOf is not null safe.
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(listToCopy));
}
```

Does not work with `copyOf` and also not with `unmodifiableList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from making an immutable copy of the list in the constructor, you also need to update its getter.

```
public List<String> ex() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(ex);
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks a lot four your answer. I tried it and the spot bugs warning disappears.  But I am still a bit disappointed as this seams to be unnecessary copying, just to satisfy spot-bugs. It is not actually needed as the list was already immutable before and therefore could not be changed after calling the getter.